# Accordion... body is collapsing when clicked on

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I want it so that only when I click on the .tab, it expands the .body; but currently when the .body is expanded, and I click on the .body, it collapses it.  How can I change this to prevent it?

Here's what I Have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#accordianFin li').click(function(){
        $('#accordianFin li.body ').slideUp();
        $('li.body', this).slideToggle();
    })
})
</script>

<ul id="accordianFin">
  <li>
    <ul>
  <li class="tab"><a>...</a></li>
  <li class="body">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery plugin: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```
$(function() {    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();  });
```